# construct dataframe rows with column counts as values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I would like to construct a dataframe as so:

```
raw_data = {'Users Status': ['Attended', 'Facilitated', 'Hosted'],
    'previous_week': [meeting_participants_df['Attended Meetings'].count(), meeting_facilitators_df['Facilitated Meetings'].count(), meeting_owners_df['Hosted Meetings'].count()],
    'current week': [meeting_participants_df2['Attended Meetings'].count(), meeting_facilitators_df2['Facilitated Meetings'].count(), meeting_owners_df2['Hosted Meetings'].count()]}
host_facilitators_participants = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Attended', 'Facilitated', 'Hosted'])
host_facilitators_participants
```

However, this returns column headers only. I would like to avoid assigning variable names to the column counts...

P.S. the reason for this is to put the values into a grouped bar chart using matplotlib & plotly

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is desired output.
So I try more possibilities:

You can use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
print raw_data   
{ 'current week': [2, 4, 3], 
  'Users Status': ['Attended', 'Facilitated', 'Hosted'], 
 'previous_week': [2, 4, 3]}

#omit column names 
host_facilitators_participants = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
print host_facilitators_participants
  Users Status  current week  previous_week
0     Attended             2              2
1  Facilitated             4              4
2       Hosted             3              3

#set index from column Users Status
host_facilitators_participants = host_facilitators_participants.set_index('Users Status')
print host_facilitators_participants
              current week  previous_week
Users Status                             
Attended                 2              2
Facilitated              4              4
Hosted                   3              3

#transpose dataframe
host_facilitators_participants = host_facilitators_participants.T
print host_facilitators_participants
Users Status   Attended  Facilitated  Hosted
current week          2            4       3
previous_week         2            4       3
```

Or you can use [`from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
#omit 'Users Status': ['Attended', 'Facilitated', 'Hosted'] from dictionary    
print raw_data1  
{'current week': [2, 4, 3], 'previous_week': [2, 4, 3]}

#use from_dict for creating dataframe,  keys of dict should be rows
host_facilitators_participants = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(raw_data1, orient='index')
#set column names
host_facilitators_participants.columns=['Attended', 'Facilitated', 'Hosted']
print host_facilitators_participants
               Attended  Facilitated  Hosted
current week          2            4       3
previous_week         2            4       3

#set index in dataframe constructor
host_facilitators_participants = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1, 
                                              index=['Attended', 'Facilitated', 'Hosted'])
print host_facilitators_participants
             current week  previous_week
Attended                2              2
Facilitated             4              4
Hosted                  3              3
```

Notice: [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.count.html) doesn't count `NaN` values in columns.

Comment: Count gives me a numpy int32 e.g. (576) for my column counts (eg. meeting_participants_df['Attended Meetings'].count()). I would like to reference the column counts for the values in my dataframe when creating my dataframe.

Comment: Referencing is problematic if creating `df` by `pd.DataFrame`. But what is your desired output?

Comment: I will be making a grouped histogram from this, using matplotlib (or pandas plotting lib?) and plotly

Comment: Please check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#histograms